# Model not rendering on three.js

Tags: three.js

I am new to Three.js. I was trying to load a STL model using the `STLLoader` from the examples. The [model](https://www.ozeki.hu/index.php?owpn=1116) I am trying to load is the Eiffel Tower model. I downloaded the STL file which is in ASCII format and almost 33 MB in size. I have the following setup to display the model:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 5% auto; }
            canvas { width: 80%; height: 80% }
            #progress {
                margin-bottom: 2%;
                min-width: 50%;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/STLLoader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="progress"></div>
        <script>
            // window properties
            const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

            // camera properties
            const FOV = 35;
            const ASPECT_RATIO = windowWidth / windowHeight;
            const NEAR = 0.1;
            const FAR = 1000;

            // scene settings
            const SCENE_BKG = new THREE.Color("rgb(220,220,220)");

            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = SCENE_BKG;

            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( FOV, ASPECT_RATIO, NEAR, FAR );

            const STLLoader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            STLLoader.load('./sample_stl/Eiffel_tower_sample.STL', function(geometry) {
                console.dir(geometry);
                const materials = [];
                const nGeometryGroups = geometry.groups.length;

                let colorMap = []; // Some logic to index colors.
                let material;

                // create a random colorMap
                let startColor = 0x010101;
                let clr = startColor;
                let count = 0;
                while (count++ < nGeometryGroups) {
                    colorMap.push(clr);
                    clr = ( parseInt(clr, 16) + startColor ).toString();
                }
                console.log(colorMap);

                for (let i = 0; i < nGeometryGroups; i++) {

                        material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                            color: colorMap[i],
                            wireframe: false
                        });

                }

                materials.push(material);
                const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
                console.dir(mesh);
                scene.add(mesh);
                // should i call animate here?


            }, function (xhr) {
                // show progress here
                progressBar.innerHTML = `<span style="color: green;">${(xhr.loaded/xhr.total) * 100}%</span> have been loaded`; 
            }, function(err) {
                console.error('[!] Fatal Error: Could not load model');
                console.error(err);
            });
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( windowWidth, windowHeight );

            const progressBar = document.querySelector('#progress');
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const animate = () => {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are two things I am not sure about. First, what is the `colorMap` array? I looked at the `MeshPhongMaterial` class documentation and figured out it was a hex color value. I copied this code directly from the STLLoader example folder [here](https://github.com/thepricehub/STLLoader/blob/master/STLLoader.js). I found a quick hack to generate some hex colors and populate the colorMap array (an empty array was throwing errors). Secondly, where should I call the `animate()` function? I tried calling it inside the `modelLoaded` handler and also outside it with the only difference being that inside the handler, it throws `Violation: handler took 500ms`. I checked the networks tab on both Firefox and Chromium to see that the STL file was loaded properly. I also printed the `Mesh` object in the console which is as follows:

```
Mesh
castShadow: false
children: []
drawMode: 0
frustumCulled: true
geometry: BufferGeometry
attributes: {position: Float32BufferAttribute, normal: Float32BufferAttribute}
boundingBox: null
boundingSphere: Sphere {center: Vector3, radius: 71.76963889659893}
drawRange: {start: 0, count: Infinity}
groups: [{…}]
index: null
morphAttributes: {}
morphTargetsRelative: false
name: ""
type: "BufferGeometry"
userData: {}
uuid: "28A4B269-2828-477D-9C6D-5C9A30E95A7F"
_listeners: {dispose: Array(1)}
drawcalls: (...)
id: 7
offsets: (...)
__proto__: EventDispatcher
layers: Layers
mask: 1
__proto__: Object
material: Array(1)
0: MeshPhongMaterial {uuid: "1E33986A-A979-49C0-ADF5-823CACC6F3AA", name: "", type: "MeshPhongMaterial", fog: true, blending: 1, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
matrix: Matrix4
elements: Array(16)
0: 1
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 1
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
10: 1
11: 0
12: 0
13: 0
14: 0
15: 1
length: 16
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
matrixAutoUpdate: true
matrixWorld: Matrix4
elements: Array(16)
0: 1
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 1
6: 0
7: 0
8: 0
9: 0
10: 1
11: 0
12: 0
13: 0
14: 0
15: 1
length: 16
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false
name: ""
parent: Scene
autoUpdate: true
background: Color {r: 0.8627450980392157, g: 0.8627450980392157, b: 0.8627450980392157}
castShadow: false
children: [Mesh]
fog: null
frustumCulled: true
layers: Layers {mask: 1}
matrix: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
matrixAutoUpdate: true
matrixWorld: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false
name: ""
overrideMaterial: null
parent: null
position: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
quaternion: Quaternion {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1, _onChangeCallback: ƒ}
receiveShadow: false
renderOrder: 0
rotation: Euler {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _order: "XYZ", _onChangeCallback: ƒ}
scale: Vector3 {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
type: "Scene"
up: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0}
userData: {}
uuid: "3F9C4993-4CB4-4541-9C64-34FCBB12B1E3"
visible: true
_listeners: {dispose: Array(2)}
eulerOrder: (...)
id: 4
modelViewMatrix: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
normalMatrix: Matrix3 {elements: Array(9)}
useQuaternion: (...)
__proto__: Object3D
position: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
quaternion: Quaternion {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1, _onChangeCallback: ƒ}
receiveShadow: false
renderOrder: 0
rotation: Euler {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _order: "XYZ", _onChangeCallback: ƒ}
scale: Vector3 {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
type: "Mesh"
up: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0}
userData: {}
uuid: "72BA29AF-F939-45F8-869A-D074E6696D7F"
visible: true
eulerOrder: (...)
id: 10
modelViewMatrix: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
normalMatrix: Matrix3 {elements: Array(9)}
useQuaternion: (...)
__proto__: Object3D
```

This is the printed Mesh object. I am not sure what's wrong and would be glad if someone can explain me how to use the `colorMap` property and also give me a definitive answer on the `animate` function calling scope.

**EDIT**
Added a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/renderedNull/z5gx64so/21/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, what is the colorMap array?

The code from your example assumes that the model's geometry has multiple [groups](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups). If this is true, it's possible to assign multiple materials to a single 3D object. However, it's not mandatory to do so. If you want just a single material color, do this:

```
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

> Secondly, where should I call the animate() function?

`three.js` examples normally have an `init()` and an `animate()` function. Meaning you start animating right after initializing the scene (creating camera, renderer, lights etc.). You can do this also in your application, however the STL file will pop in as soon as its loading and parsing progress is finished. As an alternative, you can also start animating in the `onLoad()` callback. It really depends on your use case (so there is no right or wrong).

`three.js R111`

Comment: I changed the colorMap and just used one material as you showed in the example. However, I still don't see the model being rendered. Only the scene background (gainsboro color) is visible; also, the progress shows 100% which, means that the model was loaded. Also I added the `animate` function call inside `onLoad`. Same problem. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Try to add some lights to your scene. Lit materials like `MeshPhongMaterial` are only visible if light sources are present.

Comment: I updated the fiddle by adding a `DirectionLight` into the scene. Still no model on display unfortunately.

Comment: Your fiddle does not work because `STLLoader` is not imported correctly. Even if I fix this, it's not possible to load your model because of CORS issues: https://jsfiddle.net/L21kogsq/. Consider to share your example as a github repo.

Comment: Here is a github repo with the code https://github.com/zeroN1/simple-3d. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, it seems the position of your camera was not optimal. I've saved the updated code in your `index.html` file in the following jsbin :https://jsbin.com/bacitusete/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks so much. It actually worked. Just two questions: (1) the animation you added `mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * (-0.5)` is that necessary to draw the model? (2) I tried loading other models and it seems that the camera position used in this example is not perfect for other models (it moves to the side); is there any way I can better position my camera for any loaded model based on the model definition? Again, really appreciate your help!

Comment: (1) Not it's not necessary but in this way to model is oriented correctly. (2) Yes, you can do this automatically based on the AABB of the model. Study the following source code for more information: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/master/src/viewer.js#L220-L249